# Positioning a pgfplot inside tikz (understand anchors, rotation and scale)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, positioning, scaling, anchor

I'm trying to rotate the plotting of a parabola above a `tikzpicture`. (For a parabola, I can achieve what I want without using `pgfplots`, but I need the same for more complicated plots.) I can't seen to understand how the anchors for rotation work, neither how does the `tikz` scaling impacts on them. What I've got so far:

[image: with scale]

[image: without scale]

The difference between the pictures is that the first has a `scale=1.5` modifier added to the `tikzpicture`. The blue parabola should be where the black one is (i.e., with center at `b`). The green parabola is added only for visualization of a weird behavior.

1. About the scale. I've seen [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56864/pgfplots-axis-cs-nodes-inside-a-scaled-tikzpicture), but as far as I understand, I don't use outside elements in my `pgfplot` calculations (only the origin placement). Hence scaling after the plotting is done should be no problem. Furthermore, as seen in the second figure, even when the `scale` input is removed, the positioning and size of the parabolas is still incorrect. Why is it that the `scale` is not working properly with the `pgfplot`? How is it possible that the scaling moves the point `(0,0)` upwards or downwards ("weird behaviour")? (maybe the second question is related to bad anchoring?)
   Moreover, why is the blue parabola so big, even without scaling, if the plot domain is the same used for the black parabola?
2. About the rotation. I took the approach from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134904/how-to-rotate-a-pgfplot) and it seems to work fine, although with the wrong anchor.  However, I don't understand fully its statement. I get that `rotate around={90:(current axis.origin)}` rotates around the second entry, `(current axis.origin)`. But what is the current axis? What other options could I write instead of that?
   I couldn't find anything about rotating the whole plot in the `pgfplots` [manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots).
3. About the anchoring. It doesn't work and I don't understand why not. Without the `at` option, the misplacement is even worse (and I actually need that option, because I want to manually set the plot placement, as done [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167379/positioning-pgfplots-axis-in-tikzpicture)). My understanding: the `at` option fixes a point `A` in the `tikzpicture` coordinates; then, the `anchor` option takes a location `B` of the `pgfplot` coordinates and fixes it in the `tikzpicture`, directly over `A`.  Is this correct? If so, why is my code not working? The point `(0,0)` is in the middle of `a` and `b` and therefore placing the plot origin at `(0,0)` and afterwards rotating the plot around its origin should be enough to place the blue parabola over the black one (and the green parabola over `a`).

Of course a running code is welcome, but mostly I want to understand how this placement works, so that I can use it for other complicated plots as well. Thank you in advance!

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15} %this line removes the warning but cuts the picture

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    [scale=1.5] %remove this line for figure 2
    
    \coordinate (a) at (-1,0);
    \coordinate (b) at (1,0);
    \coordinate (o) at (0,0);
    
    %draw reference line
    \filldraw (a) node[below]{$a$} (a) {} circle (0.3pt);
    \filldraw (b) node[below]{$b$} (b) {} circle (0.3pt);
    \draw[-] (-1.5,0)--(1.5,0);
    
    %these are out of scale and misplaced
    \begin{axis}[at={(o)}, %where the origin is supposed to be
        anchor=origin, % i have tried center as well
        rotate around={-90:(current axis.origin)}, % Supposed to rotate around the origin
        domain=-1:1,
        hide axis]
        \addplot[blue] {x^2+1};
    \end{axis}

    \begin{axis}[at={(o)}, %where the origin is supposed to be
            anchor=origin, % i have tried center as well
            rotate around={90:(current axis.origin)}, % Supposed to rotate around the origin
            domain=-1:1,
            hide axis]
            \addplot[green] {x^2+1};
    \end{axis}
    
    %what it should be
    \draw[black, rotate=-90]   plot[smooth,domain=-1:1] (\x, {(\x)^2+1});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can put the axis environment inside a scope and position the scope using `shift=(A)` or `shift={(x,y)}`.  Not sure if you can rotate it.

Comment: The axis is positioned relative to the lower left corner, which corresponds to (0,0) and (rel axis cs: 0,0) but **not** (axis cs: 0,0).  It would be easier to position everything relative to axis cs: coordinates than to position pgfplots relative to TikZ coordinates.

Comment: pgfplots is immune to [scale].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To scale the plot, adjust the width (height).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15} %this line removes the warning but cuts the picture

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    %[scale=1.5] %remove this line for figure 2
    
    \begin{axis}[scale only axis, axis equal image, width=4cm,
        rotate=90,
        domain=-1:1,
        hide axis]
        \addplot[blue] {x*x+1};
        \addplot[green] {-1-x*x};
        \coordinate (a) at (axis cs: 0,1);
        \coordinate (b) at (axis cs: 0,-1);
    \end{axis}
   
    %draw reference line
    \filldraw (a) node[below]{$a$} {} circle (0.3pt);
    \filldraw (b) node[below]{$b$} {} circle (0.3pt);
    \draw[-] ($(a)!1.5!(b)$)--($(b)!1.5!(a)$);
 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

---

This attempts to move the pgfplots instead.  Not quite sure where the small offsets are coming from.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15} %this line removes the warning but cuts the picture

\newsavebox{\tempboxA}
\newsavebox{\tempboxB}

\begin{document}
\savebox{\tempboxA}{\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[scale only axis, axis equal image, height=2cm,
        rotate=-90,
        domain=-1:1,
        hide axis]
        \addplot[blue] {x*x+1};
        \coordinate (A) at (axis cs:0,0);
  \end{axis}
  \begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
    \path (A);
    \pgfgetlastxy{\xA}{\yA}
    \global\let\xA=\xA
    \global\let\yA=\yA
  \end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
\end{tikzpicture}}%
%
\savebox{\tempboxB}{\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[scale only axis, axis equal image, height=2cm,
        rotate=90,
        domain=-1:1,
        hide axis]
        \addplot[green] {x*x+1};
        \coordinate (B) at (axis cs:0,0);
  \end{axis}
  \begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
    \path (B);
    \pgfgetlastxy{\xB}{\yB}
    \global\let\xB=\xB
    \global\let\yB=\yB
  \end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
\end{tikzpicture}}%
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
    %[scale=1.5] %remove this line for figure 2
    
    \coordinate (a) at (-1,0);
    \coordinate (b) at (1,0);
    \coordinate (o) at (0,0);
    
    %draw reference line
    \filldraw (a) node[below]{$a$} {} circle (0.3pt);
    \filldraw (b) node[below]{$b$} {} circle (0.3pt);
    \draw[-] (-1.5,0)--(1.5,0);
    
    \node[above right, xshift={-\xA}, yshift={-\yA}, inner sep=0pt] at (o) {\usebox\tempboxA};
    \node[above right, xshift={-\xB}, yshift={-\yB}, inner sep=0pt] at (o) {\usebox\tempboxB};
    
    %what it should be
    \draw[black, rotate=-90]   plot[smooth,domain=-1:1] (\x, {(\x)^2+1});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```